# How to split JSON data in SQL Server if JSON contains a delimiter?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

````
declare @json1 varchar(max)
set @json1 = '{"ProtocolModification":{"ProtocolModificationDynamicData":"protocol3¥protocol4¥","checkboxdata1":"yes¥¥","DynamicDemonstrationstoBehaviorTechnician":"behav 2¥jryjrjrjryjjrj¥","checkboxdata2":"yes¥yes¥","DynamicEvaluationofProgress":"hthrhehehewrhyew¥","checkboxdata3":"¥"}}'
```?

I have my JSON data in this format. 

If I have 3 columns `Data1, Data2, Data3`, I want my records in `Data1-protocol3`, `Data2-protocol4` by splitting using the delimiter `¥`

    declare @json varchar(max) set @json = {"TreatmentsObservations":{"DynamicData":"PersonVisit 4$01:00 AM¥PersonVisit 6$01:00 AM¥PersonVisit 7$02:00 AM¥PersonVisit 8$02:00 AM¥PersonVisit 9$02:00 AM¥"}}
this is how my second json looks and i want my record set like
````

```
Data1      |    Data2
```

---------------|---------------
personVist4   |   01:00AM
personVist6   |   01:00AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's SQL Server it seems you're looking for something like this

```
declare @json1 varchar(max)
  set @json1 = '{"ProtocolModification":{"ProtocolModificationDynamicData":"protocol3¥protocol4¥","checkboxdata1":"yes¥¥","DynamicDemonstrationstoBehaviorTechnician":"behav 2¥jryjrjrjryjjrj¥","checkboxdata2":"yes¥yes¥","DynamicEvaluationofProgress":"hthrhehehewrhyew¥","checkboxdata3":"¥"}}'

select sp.[value] as ProtMods
from openjson(@json1, '$.ProtocolModification') 
              with (ProtocolModificationDynamicData             nvarchar(4000),
                    checkboxdata1                               nvarchar(4000),
                    DynamicDemonstrationstoBehaviorTechnician   nvarchar(4000),
                    checkboxdata2                               nvarchar(4000),
                    DynamicEvaluationofProgress                 nvarchar(4000),
                    checkboxdata3                               nvarchar(4000)) j1
     outer apply string_split(j1.ProtocolModificationDynamicData, '¥') sp
where sp.[value] <> ' ';
```

Output

```
ProtMods
protocol3
protocol4
```

Comment: In same json i need other records like checkboxdata1,DynamicDemonstrationstoBehaviorTechnician etc ...in same format just like for ProtocolModificationDynamicData this ..can i get that in same query or i need to write another for every record set??

Comment: I'd have to see exactly what you're looking for.  The string_split will cause duplication of the row values not involved in the split.

Comment: i want my record set same as above one....like for  checkboxdata2   record set..
Data 1 -yes Data2 - can i get this also in same query ??

Comment: When we split ProtocolModificationDynamicData there were 2 values which were translated into 2 rows from 1 row.  If the remaining columns are added to the query (add j.* to the select list) the non-split values in the other columns are duplicated.  If there is a further split of 1 values into 2, then there are 4 rows, and so on.  Is there an ordered relationship between the ProtocolModificationDynamicData and the remaining columns, i.e. does the first value in checkboxdata2 correspond to protocol3 and second value correspond to protocol4?

Comment: Is it correct, "checkboxdata1":"yes¥¥" means the "yes" corresponds to platform3.  If it corresponded to platform4 is would be "checkboxdata1":"¥¥yes"?

Comment: for platfiorm3 and platform4..checkboxData2 is record set..like if "checkBoxData":yes corresponds to platform3 ,"checkBoxData2":yes corresponds to platform4

Comment: can i use any other name instead if "value" here   ??                                                                       
value
protocol3
protocol4

Comment: Renaming the column was a quick fix.  I updated with that.

Comment: can u please give me the answer ..i updated my question...can u please check that once

Comment: What is serializing the data like this?  Could we fix that?  Because the JSON-way would be to create nested arrays instead of delimited text

Comment: i updated my second json ...here i have separated with two delimiters..i want my record set like ...in column-1:personvisit4 and in column2:01:00AM....can anyone give me the answer?

Comment: @RajatGupta if the question changes too much it's a new question.  It's Ok if this question isn't the perfect answer if it gets you closer it was useful and it might be exactly what someone else needs.